# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating

Tags: javascript, ios

I have this js function which works fine, but not on iOS

```
function hexToRGBA(hex, opacity)
{
    if (hex) {
        return 'rgba(' + (hex = hex.replace('#', '')).match(new RegExp('(.{' + hex.length / 3 + '})', 'g')).map(function(l) {
            return parseInt(hex.length % 2 ? l + l : l, 16)
        }).concat(isFinite(opacity) ? opacity : 1).join(',') + ')';
    }
}
```

On iOS it throws an error

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating (hex=hex.replace ('#','')))
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong and how can I fix it on iOS?

on MacBook works fine. Only on iPhone is not.